# Migrate paid IOS app to IAP, after a trial period

Tags: ios, storekit

I have a paid app on apple store, I wish to migrate to IAP, if use ***.****.IAP as productID for IAP, I can check transactions against this for purchase status, but for those original paid up, can I get a receipt, if so what productID do I check against?
Or should I get user to subscribe to non consumable purchase at £0.00 and at a later date, after trial period, switch store price to £0.00 and IAP price to £x.xx
Thanks

Comment: You check the original purchase date in the receipt for your app. Then check if it is before or after you introduced IAP

Comment: Thank for reply.
Hello Paul, would I get a purchase receipt , when using the newly created product ID, for app purchases without the new product id?

Comment: You can always get a receipt, even for free apps. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest

Comment: Is that a store kit 1 class, can get latest receipt in store kit 2, using  Transaction? Excuse lack of knowledge on this. Thanks Jeff

Comment: Yes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction

Comment: @Paulw11 It seems `appTransaction` is only available for iOS16, not iOS 15

Comment: You would need to use the original receipt method prior to ios 16